# CakePHP unit testing components containing db calls

Tags: unit-testing, cakephp-3.0

I'm trying to test a component in unit tests. problem I have is with database calls. I get error saying that association is not declared in my table class. But association is there, I checked by pasting code to AppController which returns data correctly.

How can I test my component code when I use associations in my query builder.

Looks like generic tableClass is used instead of my declared table class?

Comment: If a generic table class is being used, that means that your actual table class cannot be found/accessed. Without seeing your code and your test setup, it's pretty much impossible to tell where the problem might be, maybe you haven't configured the test environment correctly, or you're not invoking it correctly, maybe there's a typo somewhere in your code, maybe there's a permission problem, etc...

Comment: I'll have a look how to set up the test properly so it includes table definitions